# How to overload operator+ with common_type and template recursive type

Tags: c++

I'm not sure how to describe when the type of a template is the struct itself as shown below.

```
template<typename T> struct Point{};
Point<Point<int>> p;
```

Is that defined behavior? If so, I don't know the best way to implement it so that I can return a common_type without an error as shown below.

```
#include <iostream>

template<typename T> struct Point
{
    Point() {}
    template<typename U, typename V> Point(const U& u, const V& v): x(u), y(v) {}
    T x,y;
};

template<typename T, typename U> 
inline Point<typename std::common_type<T, U>::type> operator+(const Point<T>& p, const U& n)
{ 
    return {p.x+n, p.y+n};
}

int main() {
    Point<int> p;
    Point<double> r1 = p + 1.5; //works
    Point<Point<int>> p2;
    Point<Point<double>> r2 = p2 + 1.5; //error
    return 0;
}
```

The error is:
`no match for ‘operator+’ (operand types are ‘Point<Point<int> >’ and ‘double’)`

Comment: You're writing the class, so it's up to you whether that should make sense (in my opinion it doesn't). What should `p2 + 1.5` return if you want it to work?

Comment: `Is that defined behavior?` Yes, think of `std::vector<std::vector<int>>`

Comment: What is your question? There is no common type, so the compilation fails. Please provide an example of behavior you want. I have no idea what use you'd have for a type `Point<Point<T>>`, so you'd have to explain what is the mathematical equivalent of it at every level of recursion, and how they'd add.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

**If** you want this to work (in my opinion it shouldn't, but it's up to you), you can use `decltype(std::declval<T>()+std::declval<U>())` instead of `std::common_type<...>`.

```
#include <iostream>

template<typename T> struct Point
{
    Point(): x{}, y{} {}
    template<typename U, typename V> Point(const U& u, const V& v): x(u), y(v) {}
    T x,y;
};

template<typename T, typename U> 
inline Point<decltype(std::declval<T>()+std::declval<U>())> operator+(const Point<T>& p, const U& n)
{ 
    return {p.x+n, p.y+n};
}

template<typename T>
std::ostream &operator<<(std::ostream& os, const Point<T>& p)
{
    os << "Point<" << typeid(T).name() << ">(x=" << p.x << ", y=" << p.y << ")";
    return os;
}

int main() {
    Point<int> p;
    auto r1 = p + 1.5;
    Point<Point<int>> p2;
    auto r2 = p2 + 1.5;
    std::cout << p << "\n";
    std::cout << r1 << "\n";
    std::cout << p2 << "\n";
    std::cout << r2 << "\n";
    return 0;
}
```

I also added an overload the print out a point. Since the C++ standard has no guarantees on what `typeid(T).name()` will give you might see something different, but this is what I get:

```
Point<i>(x=0, y=0)
Point<d>(x=1.5, y=1.5)
Point<5PointIiE>(x=Point<i>(x=0, y=0), y=Point<i>(x=0, y=0))
Point<5PointIdE>(x=Point<d>(x=1.5, y=1.5), y=Point<d>(x=1.5, y=1.5))
```

`Point<i>` is `Point<int>`, `Point<d>` is `Point<double>`, `Point<5PointIiE>` is `Point<Point<int>>`, and `Point<5PointIdE>` is `Point<Point<double>>`. Note that I used `auto` for `r1` and `r2` so the types are deduced by the compiler.

Again, it's up to you whether you think this behavior makes sense for your class.

Comment: You can use `std::declval` to avoid the need for default constructibility. `decltype(std::declval<T>()+std::declval<U>())`

Comment: Neat, I didn't know about that. Thanks :)

Answer (score 0):

This is defined behaviour. To allow usage in a recursive fashion, you'll need to specialize the `std::common_type` metafunction on your `Point` class. Note that normally, defining anything within the `std` namespace results in undefined behaviour - however, the standard specifically allows you to provide specializations for some `std` templates for custom types.

```
#include <iostream>

template<typename T> struct Point
{
    Point() {}
    template<typename U, typename V> Point(const U& u, const V& v): x(u), y(v) {}
    T x,y;
};

// provide custom common_type implementation
namespace std {
    template <class T, class U>
    struct common_type<Point<T>, U> {
        using type = Point<typename std::common_type<T, U>::type>;
    };
}

template<typename T, typename U>
inline Point<typename std::common_type<T, U>::type> operator+(const Point<T>& p, const U& n) {
    return {p.x+n, p.y+n};
}

int main() {
    Point<int> p;
    Point<double> r1 = p + 1.5; //works
    Point<Point<int>> p2;
    Point<Point<double>> r2 = p2 + 1.5; //works
    Point<Point<Point<int>>> p3;
    Point<Point<Point<double>>> r3 = p3 + 1.5; //works
    // and so on
    return 0;
}
```

Answer (score 0):

This doesn't work because there is not a common type between `Point<anything>` and numeric types. You should of course ask yourself whether you want this to work to start with, and whether you simply shouldn't explicitly handle one level of nesting and stop there.

To support arbitrary nesting, what you'd want is a special case for when `Point` includes another `Point` inside of it: these are then "peeled away", since the result type for `Point<Point<T>, U>` is declared as the result of addition of `Point<T>` and `U`.

Finally, I imagine that you're assuming that `std::common_type<T,U>` results in the same type as `T{}+U{}`, so that the addition via the `Point` indirection works just like addition on the most interior fields would work. I don't have a problem there as long as you force the compiler to check that fact.

```
#include <type_traits>

template<typename T> struct Point
{
    constexpr Point() {}
    template<typename U, typename V> constexpr Point(const U& u, const V& v): x(u), y(v) {}
    T x = {}, y = {};
};

template<typename T, typename U> 
inline constexpr Point<typename std::common_type_t<T, U>> operator+(const Point<T>& p, const U& n)
{
    static_assert(std::is_same_v<std::common_type_t<T,U>, decltype(std::declval<T>() + std::declval<U>())>);
    return {p.x+n, p.y+n};
}

template<typename T, typename U>
inline constexpr Point<decltype(Point<T>{} + U{})> operator+(const Point<Point<T>>& p, const U& n)
{
    return {p.x+n, p.y+n};
}

template <class T, class U>
inline constexpr bool operator==(const Point<T> &p, const Point<U> &r)
{
    return p.x == r.x && p.y == r.y;
}

int main() {
    constexpr Point<int> p;
    constexpr Point<double> r1 = p + 1.5;
    constexpr Point<Point<int>> p2;
    constexpr Point<Point<double>> r2 = p2 + 1.5;
    constexpr Point<Point<Point<int>>> p3;
    constexpr Point<Point<Point<double>>> r3 = p3 + 1.5;
    constexpr Point<Point<Point<Point<int>>>> p4;
    constexpr Point<Point<Point<Point<double>>>> r4 = p4 + 1.5;
    static_assert(r4.x == p4.x + 1.5);
    static_assert(r4.x.x == p4.x.x + 1.5);
    static_assert(r4.x.x.x == p4.x.x.x + 1.5);
    static_assert(r4.x.x.x.x == p4.x.x.x.x + 1.5);
}
```